# configuring ProxyPass on .htaccess to show tomcat through apache http server

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess, tomcat, proxypass

I have an Apache HTTP server runing on an open 80 port and a Tomcat server running on 8080 closed port.

I can get internally the tomcat webpage using `lwp-request 127.0.0.1 8080`.

I don't have access to `httpd.conf` so i tried to configure a ProxyPass on the .htaccess file.

What i need is that the user who enters `http://www.mydomain.com/tomcat` can see the html generated by the tomcat server

I used this line in the `.htaccess`:

```
ProxyPass tomcat/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

But the only thing i get entering `http://www.mydomain.com/tomcat` is an error 500

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You see anything in your apache or tomcat logs?

Comment: i have no access to the apache http server dir, i can't see the logs nor httpd.conf file

Answer (score 7):

`proxypass` and `proxypassReverse` are available only in the server config and virtual host contexts.

in case you don't have access to the config files or whatever else reason, you could use mod_rewrite with the P flag which does the same.

your `.htaccess` file should then look like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule tomcat/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/ [P]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Rewriting the url doesn't solve the problem, the port 8080 is still closed so rewriting the url will not work.

Comment: I gave up with this problem, the machine was a hosting shared (with other customers) server with ssh, but my user account had no access to the apache http server files. So i closed my account ery upset about the service.
Thanks for the answer anyway.