# Redirect to URL and keep it hidden

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, hide

I have this small private minecraft server, and I added dynmap.

So I would like to share this map on website, BUT I don't want to use its original URL, cause it shows the server IP that I would like to keep hidden.

Map on URL:

```
http://server17.mycommunity.net:8123/
```

I want it to be seen from:

```
http://minecraft.mycommunity.net/map/
```

I would like to do this with `.httaccess` file. I've tried the settings below, but it only redirects to the `server17` address, and I would like it to stay in `/map/` URL and keep the server address hidden.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^map/$ http://server17.mycommunity.net:8123/ [L]
```

Is this possible to do it with `.htaccess` or do I have to do this some other way?

Comment: You can't internally redirect different domains it would externally redirect.

Comment: Do you have access to the server configuration files? httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

These answers looks to be close to what you need, although you might need mod_proxy installed:

- [configuring ProxyPass on .htaccess to show tomcat through apache http server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633400/configuring-proxypass-on-htaccess-to-show-tomcat-through-apache-http-server)
- [.htacess rewriting with the [P] proxy flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711189/htacess-rewriting-with-the-p-proxy-flag)

I don't use Apache regularly, so I'm not quite sure what is needed. I do know that with some configuration you can use mod_rewrite/mod_proxy to proxy content from one server at one port to another at the regular http port.  That's what you are really needing.  There is no such thing as rewriting when it comes to proxying.

However, I'm not sure exactly what that proxy entails, or if, by setting up this kind of proxy, you aren't breaking anything.